# Manipulate html string with Jquery ( in Angular application for wysiwyg editor )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, wysiwyg

I have a wysiwyg editor that uses a $scope.variable as it source of HTML.

Now i need to insert divs into certain parts of the HTML string. So i can programmatically append, prepend, remove etc. parts of the shown content in the wysiwyg. But i can't get the manipulation to work.

Should be simple to insert things into the dom right? But nothing gets appended in this example:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.obj = {};

  // html string
  $scope.obj.htmlString = ' <div class="wrapper-div">wrapper div<div class="container">container div<div class="inner-div">inner div</div></div></div>';

  // element inserted into html string ( virtual dom )
  $($scope.obj.htmlString).find('.container').prepend('<b>text inserted into container div</b>');

  // insert the elements to dom
  angular.element('.insert-here').prepend($scope.obj.htmlString);

});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ obj.htmlString }}
  <div class="insert-here">
  </div>
</body>
```

PLUNKER:

https://plnkr.co/edit/dCzQF6YYth5NFOTkVahy?p=preview

Comment: `.find('.container')` - note the `.`

Comment: Thanks! A typo i have fixed now, but i doesn't make a difference.. Check plunkr..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .container selector and get the html out of the DOM

```js
var htmlString = ' <div class="wrapper-div">wrapper div<div class="container">container div<div class="inner-div">inner div</div></div></div>';
// element inserted into html string ( virtual dom )
var $html = $('<div>' + htmlString + '</div>').find('.container').prepend('<b>text inserted into container div</b>');
htmlString = $html.html();
alert(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) to get the directive [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to accomplish this. You should not have to manipulate the DOM directly when using Angular. Check out [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/2033671)

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.insertHere = "<b>text inserted into container div</b>"
}); 
<div class="insert-here" ng-bind-html="insertHere"></div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.insertHere = "<b>text inserted into container div</b>"
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.insert-here{
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ obj.htmlString }}

  <div class="wrapper-div">wrapper div
    <div class="container">container div
      <div class="inner-div">inner div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="insert-here" ng-bind-html="insertHere">
  </div>
</body>
```